# Восстановление сайта битрикс из бэкапа

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет. Проблема такая: есть виртуальная машина с debian 12, apache, php, mariadb, phpmyadmin, скидываю в папку файлы с архивами и restore.php, чтобы восстановить копию битрикса. но при открытии restore.php ничего не происходит, помогите, пожалуйста и строго не судите)

Comment: restore.php открывается пустым

Comment: Попробуй проверить сервер скриптом https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=32&LESSON_ID=3262

Comment: этот скрипт не открывается также как и restore.php, но созданный мной test.php (c phpinfo() внутри открывается без проблем на localhost/test.php

Comment: Файл restore.php берётся с того сайта, на котором делались архивы?

Comment: "Скачайте скрипт restore.php, который доступен по ссылке в справке внизу страницы Список резервных копий (Настройки > Инструменты > Резервное копирование > Список резервных копий), либо с помощью wget . Загрузите скрипт на сервер в корень сайта."  https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=32&CHAPTER_ID=02014&LESSON_PATH=3903.4862.4894.2014

Comment: restore.php запустился, но теперь другая проблема: после завершения мастера установки отрывается не сайт, а список файлов, которые в корневом каталоге, как это можно пофиксить?

Comment: Проверьте файл .htaccess, там должны быть настройки ```Options -Indexes``` и ```DirectoryIndex index.php index.html```. Кстати, а index.php или index.html присутствует?